# How to update data using bootstrap modal in php

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to edit the profile of each user by the admin using bootstrap modal in php.
Here is the summary what I'm doing.
An anchor tag in `admin.php` page :

```
<a href="editprofile.php?id=<?php echo $ids[$i]?>"  class="fa fa-edit li-modal"  title="Edit Profile"></a>
```

Modal at `admin.php` page.

```
<div id="theModal" class="modal fade text-center">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

And javascript in the same page i.e `admin.php`

```
 $('.li-modal').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#theModal').modal('show').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

here is `editprofile.php`.
In this page I've selected that user's information who has been clicked to edit, on that above anchor tag.

```
<?php 
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db');


    if(isset($_GET['id'])){

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user where id = '$id'";
        $run = mysqli_query($connect,$query);




}
?>
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      User Information
    </div>
        <form action="edit.php" method="POST" id = 'myform'>
                <!-- body of the bootstrap modal -->
                <?php 
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){


                    ?>
                    <label for="name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name = 'fname' value = '<?php echo $row['fname'] ?>' class = 'form-control'>
                    <?php
                 }


                 ?>
```

```
 <div class="modal-footer">

   <input type="button" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Save Changes" form = 'myform'>

 </div>
```

Here is I want to do:
I want to submit a form (which is there in modal) with updated data by clicking on button that says **Save Changes** 
And I want to redirect the user back to the `admin.php` page when the admin click outside the modal or when s/he click on the close icon at the top right of the modal. 
Also want to show the success message when the admin successfully update the data.

How would I do that?

I don't know how to use a form with in a modal and then how to submit that , there may be some non standard approach , bare me with that.

Answer (score 0):

I never used bootstrap, but I have noticed that you have PHP syntax error in Your 'inline php' or mixed html/php portion inside while loop.

This:

```
<?php echo $row['fname'] ?>
```

Should look like this:

```
<?php echo $row['fname']; ?>
```

semicolon is missing in Your example.

Other than that, when You just want to echo something in mixed html/php, You don't need php open tag.

Although one should avoid mixing html/php directly as it is very old PHP fashion,
something like this is recommended (semicolon at the end is not needed in this case):

```
<?=$row['fname']?>
// wrapped in "()" is ok as well, kinda more readable 
<?=($row['fname'])?>
```

And not only that..

You cannot write html tag argument values separated with blank space everywhere. Won't work.

Not like this:

```
name = 'fname' value =
```

But like this:

```
<tagname attribute='value' otherattribute='value'> ...
```

Try to fix those first.

Comment: Well, thanks for such a good info, but these are not throwing an error, or any notice, they are working perfectly ...

Comment: Main thing I want to do is , when I click on the save changes, it should say 'data updated successfull' and then go back to the `admin.php` page.
Addition to that I've used form inside the modal but I can't submit that form after clicking 'save changes', is there anything wrong with that portion i.e form in the modal.

Comment: No, those things are not working perfectly and You seem to believe so because browsers today are may I say, immune to all such syntax errors. Like I said, I never worked with bootstrap, but I spotted what I spotted and I assure You, You would want to change these for Your own future sake of coding. Now, why it doesn't refresh? Did You wrote `header('Location: /admin.php'); ` somewhere in Your code after page submit? Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` turned on? You sure that there are no notices? My production server, one semicolon miss and it "screams". Yours should behave the same.

Comment: well thanks @Spooky for your help,
I've find out the solution from the same site yesterday,now it's working fine.